# Is it possible to update a value in a trigger by comapraing two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-administration, coalesce

I have after insert trigger with insert query ,insert looks like

```
CREATE TRIGGER After_insert_stats_to_institution
AFTER INSERT
ON ABC 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into xyz(col1,col2,col3)
( select col1,col2,col3 
  from tableA 
  join table B on .........)
UNION
( select col1,col2,col3 
  from tableb 
  join table B on .........) 
ON duplicate key 
update col3=exising-col3-value+(new col3 value inserted between mentioned 2 tables);
```

tableA and tableB having same table stricture with same condition but using for different purposes.

Could we set the value to a variable col3 on each select and use coalesce to find the correct one for the on duplicate update part?

Comment: `col3 = col3 + VALUES(col3)`

Comment: If both parts of the union return a col3 which one is the 'correct' one?

Comment: If there is ant insert on table ABC ,it will compare that value with tableA and tableB.If it finds value on tableB then it should add col3 value from tableB on duplicate key update with existing value @akina

Comment: adding to that, Is my above query is proper to compare newly inserted value between 2 query results? @Akina

Comment: *compare newly inserted value between 2 query results?* ??? You have ONE query. It consists from 2 subqueries which' outputs are combined by UNION. If each subquery produces a row with the same `col1,col2` and different `col3`, then they'll be 2 separate rows in the data for insertion/updating. And finally the table will contain one row with their `col1,col2` and summarized `col3` values in final `col3` (plus initial value if such `col1,col2` was present in the table before).

Comment: I mean newly inserted value should compare with first subquery and second subquery..If value find on any of this subquery then it should use that col3 value.I am sure that value is not present on both of the subquery .SO I used union operator . Is it ok? ,any other solution?@Akina